# WebApi Client to consume Restful WebApi class - Display ALL records

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a client in Visual Studio - a C# console app - to consume a Restful WebApi class.  I am trying to get ALL of the records displayed besides getting a record added, updated, deleted, and display 1 record.  I just need to display ALL of the records that are in the Products table.
In my Restful WebApi class, I am using migrations to seed the database.  I modified the configuration.cs in my migrations folder.  Added the following code in the Seed method

```
    protected override void Seed(RestfulWebAPIExample.Models.AppDbContext context)
    {
        context.Products.AddOrUpdate(p => p.ID,
        new Product { Name = "Milk", Price = 3.99m, Quantity = 6 },
        new Product { Name = "Eggs", Price = 4.99m, Quantity = 12 },
        new Product { Name = "Cheese", Price = 6.99m, Quantity = 7 },
        new Product { Name = "Bacon", Price = 9.99m, Quantity = 9 }
    );
}
```

I have the Product Model class in my client

```
namespace RestfulWebAPIExample
{
    class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is some of the code I have in my Program.cs in the client - to display the first record

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPIExampleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Quantity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been looking online for a long time and found some sites, but I could not find a real good example.  Can somebody give me an example or point me in the right direction?  Do I use IEnumerable somehow?

Here is my controller from the Restful WebApi class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using RestfulWebAPIExample.Models;

namespace RestfulWebAPIExample.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET api/Products
        public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            return db.Products;
        }

        // GET api/Products/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(product);
        }

        // PUT api/Products/5
        public IHttpActionResult PutProduct(int id, Product product)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != product.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ProductExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST api/Products
        [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(Product product)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = product.ID }, product);
        }

        // DELETE api/Products/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
        {
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Products.Remove(product);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(product);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool ProductExists(int id)
        {
            return db.Products.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Web API server code? Show us your controller. Also is not clear what kind of problem or exception you are encountering, please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, controller has been added to post.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, and just a few small changes and I think your problem will be solved.  Change your `GetProducts()` method like this:

```
// GET api/Products
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(IEnumerable<Product>)]
public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
{
    Ok(return db.Products);
}
```

Notice that I added the `HttpGet` attribute.  You don't *need* to do this, but I've found that specifying it helps when you have multiple GETs in one controller.  You should also look at [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), as it will make things even clearer.

In your client code, you call that endpoint like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // HTTP GET
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>();
    }
}
```

Like I said, I think you are REALLY close.

Hope that helps.